# XHR failed loading: GET

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get some return value from Web Service and i am using ajax jQuery.

I am getting these errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http....'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8181' is therefore not allowed access
>
> XHR failed loading: GET "http...".

```html
<script language="text/javascript">
  getUserValue();

  function getUserValue() {
    var number = "0000317930";
    var fullName = "NURULLAH ALTINTAŞ";
    var dataString = "{ 'number' : '" + number + "', 'fullName' : '" + fullName + "'}";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://...",
      data: {
        number: number,
        fullName: fullName
      },
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: OnSuccessGetConnectionArticles,
      failure: OnFailureGetConnectionArticles,
      error: OnErrorGetConnectionArticles
    });
  }

  function OnSuccessGetConnectionArticles(response) {
    debugger;
    $.each(response.RestResponse.result, function(index, value) {
      $("#list").append('<li><span class="tab">' + value.name + '</span></li>');
    });
  }

  function OnErrorGetConnectionArticles(response) {
    debugger;
    alert(response.d);
  }

  function OnFailureGetConnectionArticles(response) {
    debugger;
    alert(response.d);
  }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make AJAX requests across different servers? That's not directly allowed for security reasons. You can look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as a possible solution but that does require the server and client to alter their requests to support the protocol.

Comment: Yes i am, thank you.

Comment: There are lots of content about that. Please use the search bar

Comment: Yeah i can see but i am not using php or asp.net, i know what i have to do when i use them but i am trying on html page, if i solve this i will use in Phonegap for making hybrid application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **PHP** in server side you should use in your **requested page** the following code::

```
$origin = 'http://localhost:8181';
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);
```

if you are using some other anguage then you should find similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add these lines to your web.config file for Allow-Origin error.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: 1) Please answer in English when using the main SO site 2) The OP has given no indication that they are using any kind of IIS hosting where this solution would work

Comment: Harun you should write your answer in English.